# How can I "wrap" divs with Twitter Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

For "sm" and smaller I want the divs to display as:

```
[ A ]
[ B ]
[ C ]
[ D ]
[ E ]
[ F ]
```

For "md" and bigger I want the divs to display as:

```
[ A ] [ D ]
[ B ] [ E ]
[ C ] [ F ]
```

where A is aligned with D, B is aligned with E, C is aligned with F, etc.

Is this possible with Bootstrap?

I realize I could do:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div id="A"></div>
  <div id="B"></div>
  <div id="C"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div id="D"></div>
  <div id="E"></div>
  <div id="F"></div>
</div>
```

...but this doesn't ensure that B is aligned with E, e.g. when A is taller than D.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just add  `col-xs-12` (this will work in extra small and small devices) to current `col-md-6`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
      <div id="A">a</div>
      <div id="B">b</div>
      <div id="C">c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
      <div id="D">d</div>
      <div id="E">e</div>
      <div id="F">f</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### But

if you want to have them aligned by height (aka equal height), then you need to have them in the same parent, otherwise you can't AFAIK, and using `clear:left` at each odd number or `(2n+1)`

### Or

using

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

to have the visual effect (i.e - when using `border`)

#### Note

If you don't like how they are sorted, you can use `order` from `flexbox` to change their order.

so here is a example with the `order` already (and a simpler version with `clear:left` only)

```css
/*visual effect demo*/

.row > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
/* EX1- full example */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .ex1 .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .ex1 #B {
    order: 3
  }
  .ex1 #C {
    order: 5
  }
  .ex1 #D {
    order: 2
  }
  .ex1 #E {
    order: 4
  }
  .ex1 #F {
    order: 6
  }
}
/* EX2 - just to heave the same height without same height in visual effects*/

.ex2 .row > div:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
  clear: left
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container ex1">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="A" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">a</div>
    <div id="B" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">b</div>
    <div id="C" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">c</div>
    <div id="D" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd</div>
    <div id="E" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">e</div>
    <div id="F" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">f</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="container ex2">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="A" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">a</div>
    <div id="B" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">b</div>
    <div id="C" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">c</div>
    <div id="D" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd</div>
    <div id="E" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">e</div>
    <div id="F" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">f</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: This doesn't ensure that B is aligned with E, e.g. when A is taller than D.

Comment: @tedw sorry for late reply, here is the updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried the solution here http://codepen.io/tbonemp3/pen/pbAQyN and I'm not seeing the right wrapping style.

Comment: @tedw oh you didn't mentioned you wanted a layout in the same height, but here you go: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRkqRO, let me know if you want me to update the answer

Comment: The ordering of the divs is not correct.  First column should have [A,B,C] and second column should have [D,E,F]

Comment: DID YOU READ MY ANSWER? **If you don't like how they are sorted, you can use order from flexbox to change their order. (which I can update the answer to add it)**

Comment: Can you please provide an example using flexbox?  Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116745/discussion-between-tedw-and-dippas).

Comment: Updated answer, take a look

Comment: Hey @dippas I see the correctly ordered divs using flexbox, thanks for that.  I guess I was looking for something more generic where I wouldn't need to specify a style for each div.  Maybe I should consider other layout options besides bootstrap and flexbox.

Comment: I want to leave this question open in case there are other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You actually got it right.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <div id="A">a</div>
    <div id="B">b</div>
    <div id="C">c</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <div id="D">d</div>
    <div id="E">e</div>
    <div id="F">f</div>
</div>
```

Make sure each div the the same height for them to line up accordingly.