# Change order of columns in bootstrap3 at breakpoint

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build some kine of registration formular that currently consists of 3 groups of elements.

1. a set of inputs (blue)
2. a checkbox + submit button (green)
3. some more inputs (orange)

Initially i had a two column layout where blue and green are in the left and orange is the right column (as shown in the left drawing). When the screen gets narrow the orange box breaks below the green box. But as the green box contains the submit button I'd prefer to have orange break (kind of) between the blue and the green box as shown in the right drawing.

I have tried to play with push and pull classes provided by bootstrap but was not able to get what I wanted. At the moment I'm not even sure if this is actually possible.

The "best" result was just puting the 3 boxes as `col-md-6` in order blue, orange and green but as the orange box is taller than the blue one the top of the green aligns with the bottom of the orange one.

I really hope someone has an idea on how to achieve my desired behaviour

[image: layout sample]

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**:
In my opinion this question is not a duplicate of [How can I "wrap" divs with Twitter Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256768/how-can-i-wrap-divs-with-twitter-bootstrap-3)

I'll try to provide a better sample on my current situation.

My current situation looks like this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObNXxr
I used the same border color as in the image for the boxes.

for narrow screens this has the desired behaviour but on wider screens the top border of the green box is on the same line as the bottom border of the orange box. But I'd like to have the green box right below the blue box as shown in the left drawing in the image.

**UPDATE -> ANSWER**

*unfortunately i cant post this as answer as the question is falsely closed as duplicate*

I found the solution. you can see an update codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWMmvZ

I solved the issue by adding a

```
@media ( min-width : 992px) {
    .register .right-panel {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

and added `register` class on the `row` div and `right-panel` on the panel that should be visible on the right (the orange one). This allows the green box to move up right below the blue on large viewport and snaps the orange between blue and green on smaller screens.

Comment: @dippas I updated the question... do you still think this is a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :**

```css
body { padding-top: 50px; }
.content {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

body::before {
  content: "xs";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999999;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width : 768px) { 
  body::before { 
    content: "sm"; 
  }
}
@media (min-width : 992px) { 
  body::before { 
    content: "md"; 
  }
}
@media (min-width : 1200px) { 
  body::before { 
    content: "lg"; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Column A</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Column B</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This Might Be Helpful....
**Note : Ckeckout In Browser..**

**Solution 2 :**

add following code in css :

```
.col-md-push-6 {
left: 50%;
}

.col-md-pull-6 {
right: 50%;
}
```

Checkout This Snippest :

```css
body { padding-top: 50px; }
.content {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

body::before {
  content: "xs";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999999;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.col-md-push-6 {
left: 50%;
}
 
.col-md-pull-6 {
right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Column A</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Column B</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if i do not understand what you snippets are meant to do or if they are buggy but for me both only show the columns below of each other.

Comment: Also: I updated my question and also added a codepen sample to show my current situation and try to better explain my issue. Thanks! :)